# Multiple Highcharts JavaScript Update very slow. Any options to increase speed?

Tags: javascript, performance, highcharts

I have multiple Highcharts on the same page, and I update them all at the same time using a combobox which selects the individual to be shown at the charts.

All the Highcharts are quite simple, with 3-4 line or column series each, and a limited number of observations per chart (around 10-12).

For updating the charts I use a JS function, and I've tried two options:

**First option:**

```
chart1.update({
    series: [{data: mybankjson["data"]["spr_t_tva"]},
              {data: mybankjson["data"]["enf_t_tva"]},
              {data: mybankjson["data"]["hogares_t_tva"]}],
    title: {text: 'Tasas de variación interanual del crédito. SPR<br>('+ecode+'-'+anombre+')'}
});
```

**Second option:**

```
chart1.series[0].setData(mybankjson["data"]["spr_t_tva"])
chart1.series[1].setData(mybankjson["data"]["enf_t_tva"])
chart1.series[2].setData(mybankjson["data"]["hogares_t_tva"])
chart1.setTitle({text:'Tasas de variación interanual del crédito. SPR<br>('+ecode+'-'+anombre+')'})
```

There are around 40 charts to be updated using first or second option. Both are really slow (around .5 seconds EACH chart), so using the combobox to quickly view charts for different individuals is mainly impossible.

Any ideas? The size of the `.json` file (`mybankjson`) might be an issue?

Comment: Have you checked the speed of retrieving your data before anything is rendered onto highcharts? A simple method may be to not run the `chart1.update` but rather just output the data as the array you get it. If it takes just as long, you know the issue resides with the data retrieval process

Comment: In your case setData should be faster, If you are updating multiple points at the same time, set the redraw parameter to false: [Highcharts.Series#update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update),(value, false). When all updates are done, call the chart.redraw() function to redraw the chart only once.

Comment: Additionally, you can check the  [#boost-module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module#boost-module) to increase speed.

Comment: Sebastian hajdus, I understand boost-module is only for updating charts with series having many data points, not just 10-12 as this case.